# Allow the node preprocess function to be called after setting the theme function in hook_node_view()

Tags: 7, theming

In `mymodule_node_view()`, I set the theme function to be used with the following code.

```
$node->content['#theme'] = "my_custom_theme_function";
```

Now the node preprocess function (`mymodule_preprocess_node()`) is not called anymore.

How do I let Drupal run my node preprocess function, even if I set my theme function to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that line, you set the theme function for all the content shown for the node. Your code should be similar to the following one, taken from the documentation for [hook_node_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7).

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $node->content['mymodule_field'] = array(
    '#markup' => $additional_field,
    '#weight' => 10,
    '#theme' => 'mymodule_custom',
  );
}
```

As to why your code is setting the theme function for all the node content, see the code executed by [node_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7). (The comments are mine.)

```
  // This is the function that invokes hook_node_view().
  node_build_content($node, $view_mode, $langcode);

  $build = $node->content;

  // $node->content['#theme'], the value you set, becomes $build['#theme'].

  unset($node->content);

  // The following lines don't set anymore $build['#theme'], since you have already set it.
  // It is similar to executing the following code:
  //   $a = array('first' => "I am the first");
  //   $a += array('first' => "The array will never get this value");
  //
  // If you print the value of $a, you will see it is as it was first set.

  $build += array(
    '#theme' => 'node',
    '#node' => $node,
    '#view_mode' => $view_mode,
    '#language' => $langcode,
  );

  // Now the code is going to use your theme function, which means that not even
  // the node preprocess function is executed.
```

Normally, what you want to do is adding a new content to the render array for the node. That is what the code I show in the first snippet does.

If you really wanted to change the theme function used for the node, then you should simply implement [hook_theme_registry_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7), and redefine the function associated with the `node` theme function.

Keep in mind that once you change the used theme function, also the preprocess function changes; in your case, if `theme_my_custom_theme_function()` is your theme function, then the preprocess function is `mymodule_preprocess_my_custom_theme_function()`.

Comment: This complicates it a bit. I only want to change the theme for one node type, which means to output this node type with a completely custom html (I didn't write it originally, but the change of #theme was inside an `if($node->type=='myspecial')`). And still have a preprocess function called, to load javascript etc. This would normally be done in a theme (like adaptive theme) using a custom tpl.php for a node type, but I need this html defined by a module, independent of the theme. If I change the theme registry, it will change the node theme for all node types.

Comment: The theme function receives three arguments: the node, the view mode, and the language. If the theme should be applied to specific content types, `$node->type` is available.

Comment: So, when I use the theme function (as originally) then the preprocess function is not called. On the other hand, when I use theme_registry_alter, then it applies to all node types (because it's called when clearing cache, not when node is displayed). I need something that applies only for one node type and allows preprocess functions being called (and allows to rewrite the node HTML completely).